# where and how to store laravel passport authentication token and send request from front-end with that token?

Tags: reactjs, laravel-passport

i've created a laravel passport api based authentication.and using react js as frontend.when i send login request with email,password my backend send me authentication token.now where should i store this token?? if i want store it in cookies how to do that?? and how to send this with frontend ajax request??

actually i'm totally new.so if this question sound stupid ,i'm sorry..

this is my login function:

```
public function login()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('AppName')->accessToken;
            return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorised'], 401);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the token to local Storage on react js.It is one of the method to store and access the token.

```
 localStorage.setItem("token", token value)
```